# rounded corners to a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Currently the legends of my chart that I generate in c3.js are rectangles of colors, I would like to change it by circles. how can I do it?

[image]

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
      columns: [
          ['data1', 30],
          ['data2', 120],
      ],
      type : 'donut',
      onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
      onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
      onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); },
      label:true,
  },
  donut: {
      title: "Iris Petal Width",
       label: {
       /*format: function(value, ratio, id)
       {
         return d3.format('')(value)
       },*/
       show: false
      }
  }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JD52FXdZxEIcgP865w4h?p=preview)

Comment: A bit complicated for such a simple problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/c3js/KHUD20RP_hs.  There may be an updated solution to this, but this is what I used.

Comment: Just for your information, those are not rectangles. They are line (`<line>`) elements.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way (terrible?!) to do what you want:

CSS changes:

```
.c3-legend-item-tile {
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

JS changes:

```
const legendTiles = document.getElementsByClassName('c3-legend-item-tile');
for (const tile of legendTiles) {
    const x1 = tile.getAttribute('x1');
    tile.setAttribute('x2', x1);
}
```

See [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PYmYyiXAJaJK9nehAZ4Z?p=preview)

Comment: This is a good solution, but you're not using any D3 in your answer. Instead of writing an answer myself, I just made a plunkr with your solution incorporated using D3, have a look (lines 45-48): http://plnkr.co/edit/i8sdSP08o1LL0JWcM7Rc?p=preview. Feel free to add it to your answer if you want. Also, OP can play with `x1` and `x2` to  better position the lines.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Why do they look pixelated? It does not look like a perfect circle ? @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @yavg They do look like a perfect circle to me (using Chrome).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, in fact in firefox it is not a perfect circle either ... :(

Comment: @GerardoFurtado is it a good idea to add a circle with an 'append' in your code of d3.js where the lines are modified?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the lines and append circles in their positions.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado A little example of my solution http://plnkr.co/edit/pIvsaOiF3dMP5GlNXl14?p=preview only first circle.. in my real problem, I have fix my problem! thanks